# Jenkinsをsvnのcommitからhookできません

Tags: centos, apache, tomcat, svn, jenkins

Jenkinsをsvnのcommitからhookできません。

【環境】

- CentOS 6.7(VirtualBox)
- apache＋tomcat8(ajp連携)
- Jenkins(warファイルをtomcatのwebappsに配置、rpmのインストールはしていない)
- subversion

【症状】

- svnのpost-commitファイルにJenkinsのジョブ呼び出し(wget)を記述していますが、ジョブが実行されません。svnをコミット後、「コミット中」がずっと続き、タイムアウトするかキャンセルするまでずっとその状態です。タイムアウト後にジョブの状態を見ても、ビルド失敗にはなっていないので、そもそも接続できていないようです。

【その他検証結果】

- post-commitファイルを、コミットをトリガーとせず直接シェル実行すると、無事jenkinsのジョブは実行され、ビルドも成功します。Jenkinsのビルド実行ボタンを選択しても、同様に成功します。
- post-commitでwhoamiしてみると、**コミットトリガー時はapache**、**シェル実行時はroot**となっています。(**これが原因？)**
- Jenkins側では、ポーリング設定しています(スケジュールは空)。
- セキュリティ認証はしていません。
- wget呼び出し

  ```
  wget http://localhost/jenkins/job/<ジョブ>/build?delay=0sec
  ```

  です。

八方塞がりで困っています。
ご指摘や疑義などありましたら、お聞かせください。

※ yahoo社の質問サービスも使用したのですが、回答が得られなかったため、こちらで質問させてください。※

**2015-11-04 9:37 追記**

※ コメント欄の内容を転記します。

> > post-commit スクリプト内の wget の実行部分を
> >
> > `wget --timeout=5 -o /tmp/svn_commit.log http://localhost/jenkins/job/<ジョブ>/build?delay=0sec`
> >
> > とした上で svn commit を実行してみてはどうでしょうか。
>
> 下記のログを取得することができました。

```
--2015-11-04 09:02:09--
(try:1) localhost/jenkins/job/<;ジョブ>/build?delay=0sec
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... failed: Permission denied.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Permission denied. Retrying. ……
--2015-11-04 09:02:19--
(try:20) localhost/jenkins/job/<;ジョブ>/build?delay=0sec
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... failed: Permission denied.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Permission denied. Giving up.
```

Comment: post-commit スクリプト内の wget の実行部分を `wget --timeout=5 -o /tmp/svn_commit.log http://localhost/jenkins/job/<ジョブ>/build?delay=0sec` とした上で `svn commit` を実行してみてはどうでしょうか。`/tmp/svn_commit.log` に何か手掛かりとなる様な事が出力されるかもしれません。

Comment: >argus様  
ご助言ありがとうございます。  その通り実行してみたら、下記のログを取得することができました。  

--2015-11-04 09:02:09--  (try:1)  http://localhost/jenkins/job/<ジョブ>/build?delay=0sec
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... failed: Permission denied.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Permission denied.
Retrying.

……

--2015-11-04 09:02:19--  (try:20)  http://localhost/jenkins/job/<ジョブ>/build?delay=0sec
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... failed: Permission denied.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Permission denied.
Giving up.

権限がうまくいっていないようですが、これはapacheユーザで実行するうえで、何に対するどのような権限がないのかわからなく、解決することができませんでした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ログの内容を質問欄に追加します。

Comment: >argus様
ありがとうございます。

Comment: もしかするとこれは SELinux 関連の問題かもしれません。root 権限で `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on` を実行して、`svn commit` を試してみていただけますか。

Comment: @argus
教えていただいた手法で、無事に解決することができました。誠にありがとうございます。お手数おかけしますが、回答にご記入いただいてもよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄より転記

> > もしかするとこれは SELinux 関連の問題かもしれません。root 権限で
> >
> > `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`
> >
> > を実行して、svn commit を試してみていただけますか。
>
> 無事に解決することができました。